# Oracle group by and OR query optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

```
SELECT BATCH_ID,
  BU_CODE,
  BU_TYPE,
  BATCH_TYPE,
  BATCH_GROUP_ID,
  STATUS,
  UPD_DTIME
FROM BATCH_T
WHERE (BU_CODE, BU_TYPE, BATCH_TYPE, UPD_DTIME) IN
  (SELECT BU_CODE,
    BU_TYPE,
    BATCH_TYPE,
    MAX(UPD_DTIME)
  FROM BATCH_T
  WHERE STATUS = 'CLOSED'
  GROUP BY BU_CODE,
    BU_TYPE,
    BATCH_TYPE
  )
OR UPD_DTIME >= SYSDATE - 5;
```

As in above Oracle Query with out OR condition its giving quick response, But with OR condition its taking so much time. Can you please help how to improve the response time of above query.

Comment: Execution plan would help here to identify the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the last closed record and everything from the last five days.  Use window functions!

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT b.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BU_CODE, BU_TYPE, BATCH_TYPE, STATUS ORDER BY UPD_DTIME DESC) as seqnum
      FROM BATCH_T b
     ) b
WHERE UPD_DTIME >= SYSDATE - 5 OR
      (STATUS = 'CLOSED' AND seqnum = 1);
```

This should be faster than any method using `IN`/`EXISTS` and aggregation.  It is also simpler to write.

Comment: 'OR BATCH_ID IN
  (SELECT BATCH_ID
  FROM BATCH_T batch
  JOIN BATCH_GROUP_T batchGroup
  ON batch.BATCH_GROUP_ID  = batchGroup.BATCH_GROUP_ID
  WHERE batchGroup.STATUS != 'CLOSED'
  )'      ** I need to add 1 more OR condition to above query , can i add directly, will it cause any performance issue. welcoming the suggestions.**

Comment: @Gangs165700 . . . You should be able to add additional conditions to this query.

Answer (score 1):

Split the query in such a way that, there should be `AND` condition in it to get the performance gain as like below.

```
 SELECT BATCH_ID,
  BU_CODE,
  BU_TYPE,
  BATCH_TYPE,
  BATCH_GROUP_ID,
  STATUS,
  UPD_DTIME
FROM BATCH_T
WHERE UPD_DTIME >= SYSDATE - 5

UNION ALL

SELECT BATCH_ID,
  BU_CODE,
  BU_TYPE,
  BATCH_TYPE,
  BATCH_GROUP_ID,
  STATUS,
  UPD_DTIME
FROM BATCH_T
WHERE (BU_CODE, BU_TYPE, BATCH_TYPE, UPD_DTIME) IN
  (SELECT BU_CODE,
    BU_TYPE,
    BATCH_TYPE,
    MAX(UPD_DTIME)
  FROM BATCH_T
  WHERE STATUS = 'CLOSED'
  GROUP BY BU_CODE,
    BU_TYPE,
    BATCH_TYPE
  ) AND NOT UPD_DTIME >= SYSDATE - 5;
```

Comment: I need to add 1 more OR condition to above query as below,

Comment: Try to exclude the above 2 query result in that new query and include it with union all to above query

Comment: can i use Union in place of Union All.

Answer (score -1):

You can Create index for UPD_DTIME